# Entity Framework Code-first - selecting data from stored procedure with change tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

**Background:** my database exposes all CRUD operations as stored procedures. I want to utilize advantages of `DbContext` including change tracking. An out-of-box solution exists for insert, update and delete operations:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating (DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>() 
.MapToStoredProcedures(c => 
c.Update(u => u.HasName("update_person") 
               .Parameter(p => p.Id, "person_id") 
               .Parameter(p => p.Name, "name")) 
 .Delete(d => d.HasName("delete_person") 
               .Parameter(p => p.Id, "person_id")) 
 .Insert(i => i.HasName("insert_person") 
               .Parameter(p => p.Name, "department_name")));
}
```

I also found how to select the data from a stored procedure:

```
Database.SqlQuery<Person>("select_persons", parameters);
```

**Here is the question:** how can I make my `DbContext` perform change tracking of the retrieved set of records? So I'd be able to just call `SaveChanges()`?

Answer (score 0):

For a stored procedure `select_persons`, you should be able to do:

```
List<select_persons_Result> myPeople = dbContext.select_persons().ToList();
```

The class `select_persons_Result` is automatically created when you add the sproc to the model.

I don't understand what you mean about calling `SaveChanges()` if you are just doing a `select`.

Comment: `select_persons` is a stored procedure in a database. How should I map it to `DbContext` using code-first approach? I've found a way to call the procedure using `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery<T>`, but after that I want to make some changes in the resulting set from code and then call `DbContext.SaveChanges()` to save all the changes back to DB. I don't want to call the corresponding procedure manually for each added/changed/removed record.

Comment: I was confused. Your **background** implies Database First, and I did not see the Code First tag. If you already have the database, then you should have a model (.edmx file) in your solution. Update the model from the database and the classes are created. You can change the logic of the sproc without affecting the model, but if you change the signature (e.g. add a column to the return data) then just update the model again.